# Show a Custom View on textField tap just as we show a picker in the place of keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

The View is not showing on tap the code is as given below

```
let myTFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, DC.screenWidth/2-53, 30)
myT = UITextField(frame: myTFrame)
myT.delegate = self
myT.textAlignment = .Right
myT.text = "תת קטגוריה"
myT.textColor = .grayColor()
myT.delegate = self
myT.inputView = tempView
view.addSubview(myT)
```

Comment: you mean you want to show this view when the user taps on the textField?

Comment: yes I want this view to show up when the textfield is tapped

Comment: why don't you use a button instead of a textField?

Comment: do you want to show this view in place of the keyboard?

Comment: Add your customview to main view while you tap on the textfield you can achieve this by textfield delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` with `return no` and make sure your custom view fream must be at place of keyboard

Comment: Thanks @Maddyヅヅ for the suggestion

Comment: @Adeel I can also Use that but with keyboard the transition is smooth

Comment: Well I found out my mistake I was not defining the frame of the View.Error Fixed. I had not defined the view of the frame. Thanks @Maddyヅヅ and

Comment: thanks a lot @Adeel Well I found out my mistake I was not defining the frame of the View.Error Fixed. I had not defined the view of the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let myTFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, DC.screenWidth/2-53, 30)
myT = UITextField(frame: myTFrame)
myT.delegate = self
myT.textAlignment = .Right
myT.text = "תת קטגוריה"
myT.textColor = .grayColor()
myT.delegate = self
tempView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 256)
myT.inputView = tempView
view.addSubview(myT)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the `ViewController` the delegate of your `textField` and implement this method.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    /*
     * Add your view as a subview
     */

    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed my mistake but thanks for your solution. I added this to my code: tempView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 256) Please upvote if you found the question relevant